# Ciphering data value so that it cannot be seen when viewing html source code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm developing a online test. Questions and answer choices and points associated to answer choices are taken from MySQL database with PHP. And the front-end of the test is done with jQuery.

When I output the answer choices it looks like this in HTML source:

```
<li data-points="1">Answer choice text</li>
```

So it is quite easy for the user to see the points associated to answers by just looking the source of the page.

I would like to somehow hide/mask/encrypt the data-points value, so it probably must be done with PHP right after getting the value from MySQL. So after that the same html would look something like this in page source:

```
<li data-points="2f77668a9dfbf8d5848b9eeb4a7">Answer choice text</li>
```

Then this encrypted value must be read in front-end with jQuery and decrypt it so that the actual points can be calculated.

I don't know how to do this, is there any simple solution? Solution does not need to be super secure but I don't want that user can see the right answer with one click of "inspect element" or by viewing source of page. Thanks if somebody can point me to right direction!

Comment: There's nothing you can do to secure information on the client. If somebody wants to get the answer, they can.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php will allow you to encrypt and decrypt data, it would be a good starting point

Comment: Don't do this on the client - do this scoring on the server.

Comment: You can instead of data-points set id of the answer and use ajax to get the right data-point from php.